# Executor Service android как обратиться к главному потоку?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, асинхронность

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обратиться к главному потоку из ExecutorService при работе в другом потоке?

Есть следующая функция, в которую передается кастомный лиснер, и mainExecutor из main activity. execute получается я уже вызываю в главный поток, но проблема в том, что mainExecutor работает с версии API 28. У меня 23 в проекте.

```
fun getCarsList(callbackListener: (List<CarData>) -> Unit, mainThread: Executor) {
        executorService.submit<List<CarData>> {
            database.getCarDatabaseDAO().getCarsList().apply {
                mainThread.execute() {
                    callbackListener.invoke(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Есть ли какая то альтернатива передаче в метод mainExecutor?

Comment: А зачем вам эти Executor-ы? Если они не обязательны - используйте rxJava или coroutines для переключения потоков

Comment: Я учусь еще разработке в андроид. Хотел разобраться в экзекьютере, вот :)

Comment: Не знаю что это за экзекютор, но вот тут написано как его до 28 API использовать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143675/3212712

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то, что мне надо.